# Definition of a function outside of a generic class is producing a compilation error

Tags: c++, templates, default-arguments

## The context

I've written the following minimal working example

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct A {
  enum myenum {faa, fee, fii};
  myenum m_m;
  A(const myenum& m = faa): m_m(m) {}
};

int main() {
  A<int> a1;
  A<int> a2(A<int>::fii);

  std::cout << a1.m_m << std::endl
            << a2.m_m << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Compiling it and executing it results in

```
$ g++ main.cpp && ./a.out
0
2
```

## The problem

However, when the definition of the function is written outside of the class (that is, as shown below)

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct A {
  enum myenum {faa, fee, fii};
  myenum m_m;
  A(const myenum& m);
};

template <typename T>
A<T>::A(const myenum& m = A<T>::faa): m_m(m) {}

int main() {
  A<int> a2(A<int>::fii);

  std::cout << a2.m_m << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I get the following compilation error

```
$ g++ main.cpp && ./a.out
main.cpp:11:1: error: redeclaration of ‘A<T>::A(const A<T>::myenum&)’ may not have default arguments [-fpermissive]
   11 | A<T>::A(const myenum& m = A<T>::faa): m_m(m) {}
      | ^~~~
```

## The question

How can I get rid of this compilation error?

Comment: Read the error message and get rid of the default arguments in the definition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to specify the [default argument](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments) in declaration, and remove it from the definition.

> For member functions of class templates, all defaults must be provided in the initial declaration of the member function.

```
template <typename T>
struct A {
  enum myenum {faa, fee, fii};
  myenum m_m;
  A(const myenum& m = faa);
};

template <typename T>
A<T>::A(const myenum& m): m_m(m) {}
```